# flatMap is not removing nil objects from array

Tags: swift

I'm trying to remove the nil objects from array I'm getting when I'm generating objects:

```
 static func books(fromDictArray array: [[String: Any]]) -> [Books?] {

        return array.map(GettyTwo.init)
    }
```

Here I'm trying to only take the non nil objects:

```
 let inventoryBooks = [Books.books(fromDictArray: arrayOfBooks)].flatMap{$0} //this doesn't remove the nil objects
```

But if I do it this way:

```
let noNilElements = inventoryBooks.flatMap{$0}
```

This will remove the nil objects.

My question to you guys is why this is not working:

```
let inventoryBooks = [Books.books(fromDictArray: arrayOfBooks)].flatMap{$0}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're wrapping `Books.books(fromDictArray: arrayOfBooks)` in an array literal. You probably didn't mean to do that ;)

Comment: @Hamish, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Square brackets are used to make an array literal – so when you say `[Books.books(fromDictArray: arrayOfBooks)]`, you get a `[[Books?]]`, not a `[Books?]`. `flatMap(_:)` can flatten nested arrays, so that's what it does – giving you back a `[Books?]`. Just get rid of the square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have it in the [].  Instead try:

```
let inventoryBooks = Books.books(fromDictArray: arrayOfBooks).flatMap{$0}
```

Having it is the [] is making an array with one item in it, the result of the fromDictArray call.  So it's structured like [[1, 2, 3]] instead of [1, 2, 3].  So when you call flatmap it checks that one item, which that isn't nil, and returns it.

Comment: You forgot to apply your own suggestion to the code ;) And it's the flattening version of `flatMap(_:)` that is called with the `[[Books?]]`, not the optional unwrapping one – so you get back a `[Books?]`.

Comment: What do you mean?  It looks right to me now. ;)  Went too quick with the copy and paste.  Thanks.

Comment: I mean saying "So when you call flatmap it checks that one item, which that isn't nil, and returns it." isn't correct, as it's [the flattening version](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641332-flatmap) of `flatMap(_:)` being called, so there's no `nil` check going on – it's simply getting rid of one nesting layer, returning a `[Books?]`. If it were the optional unwrapping version of `flatMap(_:)` being called, you'd get back a `[[Books?]]`.